# Convert cron syntax in minutes to give schedule interval in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, cron

I have this setup on my side, where I am getting the values in minutes like 1440,60,30, etc which says that my pipeline runs at 1440 minutes, 60 minutes, and 30 minutes respectively.

From the same setup, I am getting the values in cron syntax `0 2 * * *`,`0 */8 * * *` etc,
which says my pipeline runs at 2 every day and at every 8 hours.

My query is **To maintain the consistency, How should I do to convert the cron syntax to minutes, like `0 2 * * *` to 1440, ignoring at what time it runs**.

**I just want to get the schedule intervals in minutes from the cron syntaxes**

PS: I tried with cronitor module, but failed.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

> I tried with cronitor module, but failed.

Do you mean the [croniter](https://github.com/kiorky/croniter) module? It should work – make an iterator, grab two datetimes from it and subtract one from the other. Here's an example with [cronsim](https://github.com/cuu508/cronsim):

```py
from cronsim import CronSim
from datetime import datetime

it = CronSim("0 */8 * * *", datetime(2000, 1, 1))
a = next(it)
b = next(it)
delta = b - a
delta_minutes = int(delta.total_seconds() / 60)
```

PS. Note that not every cron expression will translate cleanly to a minute interval. For example, consider `0,5 * * * *`. It runs at 0:00, 0:05, 1:00, 1:05, 2:00, 2:05 etc. So the interval will alternate between 5 and 55 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:::---

```
import datetime

import croniter

now = datetime.datetime.now()
sched = '0 22 * * 1-5'    # at 3:01pm on the 1st and 15th of every month
cron = croniter.croniter(sched, now)
cron_schedule = str(cron.get_next(datetime.datetime))

timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(cron_schedule, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print(cron_schedule)
print(timestamp.day)
print(timestamp.hour)
print(timestamp.minute)
print(timestamp.second)

Output::--
2023-02-23 22:00:00
23
22
0
0
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).